# weird behavior when deleting a chrome file

Tags: bash, google-chrome

I got this problem in which I sometimes have to delete a certain file before I can acces google-chrome. So for a quick fix I tried to make a bash file to delete it:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -r /home/NAME_OF_USER/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock
```

but everytime I want to open google-chrome after executing this little bash program, I have to open the path in the file explorer. Else I get the same error. The error says that this file should be deleted befor launch. Is there a way I can kind of "simulate" that I opened the path in the same bash program?

Comment: You might have some instance of chrome still running, holding open handle for that file.

Comment: I know what it's doing but I don't know how to program the fix for it.

Comment: @jens (Who edited the tags) I am trying to get an answer in bash code. So don't delete the bash tag. This question has bash all over it!

Comment: @CoderGuy No, this is isn't in any way a bash problem. For one thing, a single rm is completely independent of the type of shell. And then any solution to this problem is likely to not require bashisms. But if you insist, I won't mind. But I maintain that requirement is completely unnecessary. Much more than specifying a shell it would have been wise to state the OS.

Comment: did you manage to make it work? @CoderGuy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill the handlers of the file first:

```
lsof -t /home/NAME_OF_USER/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock|xargs kill
```

From `lsof` manual:

> -t       This option specifies that lsof should produce terse output with process identifiers only and no header - e.g., so that the output
>   may be    piped to kill(1).

Comment: I can't test it now because I need to turn it of and maybe it will work then but maybe not. I will try later on and then see if it works. might take a while though

Comment: `kill -9` is a blatant code smell. Any semi-well-behaved process can be killed with one of INT, HUP, QUIT or TERM and be given opportunity to clean up its mess. `kill -9` is likely the premier reason for lock files left lying around and causing problems such as the OPs!

Comment: @jens any better options? I don't want to mess up my school's pc haha

Comment: just swap ``kill -9`` for ``kill``

Comment: @klashxx that's easy. thanks bro I will see if it works but It might take a day or 2